Layot Card GoogleChats
everything good?
Does anyone already work with GoogleChats?
My problem is currently very “simple”, I’m making a birthday party for the company, but the image is huge which means that the congratulations writing doesn’t even appear, does anyone know how to resize the card?
Code:
{
  "cards": [
    {
      "header": {
        "title": "Hoje temos um aniversariante!"
      },
      "sections": [
        {
          "widgets": [
            {
              "textParagraph": {
                "text": {{ JSON.stringify($json.choices[0].message.content) }}
              }
            },
            {
              "image": {
                "imageUrl": {{ JSON.stringify($('inicio').item.json.image) }},
                "altText": "Nature"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I would like to adjust the card size

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
